# The association of found words

Tags: pattern, word-search

**Twenty-five specific words** are contained within this word search. These words are associated with **25 more words** by an unusual property.

The objectives of this puzzle are to:

1. **find at least 10 of the specific words** in the word search
2. **identify the unusual property** of these words
3. **list the words that are associated** with each word found in step 1

The 25 specific words in the word search:

- **do not include** any words with less than 4 letters
- **do not include** these words (although variations may be found):

  - SOME, MORN, TANG, CUBE, LATE, RIVE, HEEL, WALK
- **do include**:

  - fourteen 4-letter words, nine 5-letter words, and two 6-letter words

**HINT** - The property for the word association is more mathematical than linguistic.
[image: WordSearch]

```
  K L A W N Y Z O C H
  A I C D Q K N H F C  
  G F B U G N A T U N  
  E Z A D R I C B S U  
  O Y U O N L E A I M  
  P F M R L D P N O O  
  A H O I A T K J N P  
  L A C V T I S O M E  
  D W H E E L A L Y N  
  O K A R X H T E H A
```

Comment: Do proper nouns/names count?

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat - The intended words do not include any proper nouns or names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rest of the answer based on LogicanWithAHat's found answers:

> Each of the words found has the unique property that they are both entered concurrently in a padlock with letters (source: http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/march32012/).

Therefore, here's a new list:

> fusion = layout
> munch = satin
> chain = ingot
> wheel = dolls
> river = arena
> cubed = melon
> latex = shale
> banjo = ferns
> pecan = tiger
> mocha = suing
> lawn = pear
> daze = spot
> gnat = tang
> curl = wolf
> cozy = wits
> quay = wage
> hawk = pies
> link = spur
> task = bias
> open = stir
> opal = step
> loaf = twin
> road = damp

Comment: The pairs of words are correct.  A better explanation is that each word pair has a constant difference in letters of the alphabet. So, to go from fusion to layout, for each letter move 6 up the alphabet (using mod-26).

Answer (score 1):

Do all the words:

> Contain a smaller word?

Some words I found that fit the scheme:

> fusion  - ion
> wheel  - heel
> river - rive
> cubed - cube
> latex - late
> banjo - ban
> pecan - can
> task - ask
> open - pen
> opal - pal
> loaf - oaf
> curl - cur

I did find plenty of other words that don't seem to fit this pattern, though, so I'm not convinced.

Words found so far in the wordsearch itself:

> fusion (one 6 letter word left)
>
> munch, chain, wheel, river, cubed, latex, banjo, pecan, mocha (Nine 5 letter words found)
>
> <strike>walk</strike> lawn, daze, gnat, curl, cozy, quay, hawk, link, task, open, opal, loaf, road (One four letter word left)

Comment: Good progress. All of the words that you found are the intended words except for "walk". I missed that exception. The property for the word association is more mathematical than linguistic.

Comment: I tried comparing the scrabble scores of each, and that didn't get me anywhere :P Though that's not exactly a mathematical property

Comment: Ah... 'lawn' instead of 'walk'?